# r.layout.main cannot be resolved when I insert findViewById in the code

Tags: android

Here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

If I remove

```
 b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 b1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

R.layout.main is not giving any problems. But when I insert it, the error shows that R.layout.main cannot be resolved. I also refered to similar link [Button.setOnClickListener(this); error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991568/button-setonclicklistenerthis-error) , but that dint help.

Regards,

Prayag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its either one of two things:

The first: 
If your Activity class is in a different package then you have to import your class R not android.R as mentioned before

The second:
Sometimes when you are using eclipse and just added a drawable or any resource you have to clean and refresh the project to completely rebuild it,, then the R class is regenerated and seen by your other classes

Comment: Was it the first or the second solution?

Comment: Lol! I think this was the second solution. Though, this always showed up first and the best part is.... This Worked!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

look at your import ; you should import your class R , and not the android.R ;

see if that will fix the problem

Comment: you re welcome , i'm the first who answers you , 
we are here to help ;)