# What does the onclick listener (this) mean?

Tags: java, android

```
btn_Login.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In android studio.

I've seen this in countless places. What does this mean? I know how `this` operates but what is the listener called then?

This example is from: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991568/button-setonclicklistenerthis-error)

Comment: It's called a "listener".  Look at the definition of the class you're in, and see if it `implements` something interesting.

Comment: You might want to read through this first https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Just an fyi this is not an android question.  It is a Java question purely and simply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose that you have 16 Buttons and every button has `setOnclicklistener` this means that you are creating many repetitions of similar code to this in your class. And that makes your code ugly, also this is not the efficient way to write your code. So to make your code efficient you have to implement `OnClickListener()` on your activity and then for each button use `buttonX.setOnClickListener(this)`. Now use the override `onClick` method. In this method, you can use either the switch case block or if-else to identify which button is pressed. So in the `onClick` method you just have to give ids of the button.

Implement `OnClickListener` in Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
}
```

For each button use this:

```
buttonX.setOnClickListener(this);
```

After this implement override the `onClick` method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId){
        case R.id.buttonX: 
            // Do something
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in that example its defined like this
private Button btn_Login;

Button is a class
onClickListener is a listener, to set the listener he is using setOnClickListener method.

From the next time if u need to those kind of clarifications don't post in a separate thread, add a comment in that question itself.

Thank You @august alsina

Answer (score 0):

It is a listener that helps to specify the events to occur on click of a widget.

Answer (score 0):

When your class implement View.OnClickListener, you can defined your click of each button in method `public void onClick(View v)`. Keyword `this` refer to the method **onclick**. It is good to use this way when there are a lot of button in your class file. You can define following code On Create method:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and define its definition oncreate method. For example:

```
public void onClick(View v){
 int id= v.getId();
 switch (id){
    case R.id.btn1: {
     //do sth
     //break;
    }
   case R.id.btn2: {
    //do sth
   //break;
  }
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms

By writing  `btn_Login.setOnClickListener(this);`

whenever btn_login will be pressed program will go to onclick method `public void onClick(View v)`

and then you can write in the method what you want to do when button is pressed