# Error in activity regarding setOnclicklistener

Tags: android

In Android activity `setonclicklistener` method can we use `this` as a parameter? I   am getting an error. Have I made any mistake?

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); //Loading XML in to empty Window
tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);//error
```

Comment: you can share your code

Comment: can't i use this is there differnce in this and this.activity

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Loading XML in to EMpty Window
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);//error
    }

Comment: are you implements View.OnClickListener or not??

Comment: call new View.OnClickListener() instead of this

Comment: view cannot appled to this activity

Comment: i wiil do that but i want to usethis is it different from this.activity does it matters

Comment: this in onclicklistener(this);

Comment: if you want to use this, your main activity will be similar to  public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   // do your stuff
}

Comment: You can check my answer below if you don't want to use this

Comment: @kiran refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950899/what-does-the-onclick-listener-this-mean/39951408#39951408)

Comment: @kiran The code should be in the question itself (*not* in the comments) per forum rules. Besides, it's completely unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Implements the listener like below:

```
    public class youClassName extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
        {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName); 
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit); 
         btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

          } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             // your onClick code goes here!
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the OnClickListener you can basically do like:

```
    public class YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
   // Using this way you must implement OnClickListener interface ^
   // someComponents.setOnClickListener(this);

   @Override
   public void onClick (View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.your_component_id:
         // do your job here  
         break;
    }
   }
```

}

or

```
yourComponent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do your job here
    }

})
```